# How to validate a text input for only numbers using PHP

Tags: php, regex, html, validation, numbers

I have an HTML5 form to collect data and one of the inputs is for a phone number. I am using php to validate all the data the user enters. I want to validate that the user entered only numbers (from 0 to 9) using the preg_match() function. I am using "/[^0-9]/" as the regex pattern but for some reason it only allows characters (from a to z) to be validated.
Why would this happen ?

Answer (score 0):

'^' indicates the beginning of the string only when it's the first character.  Otherwise it means "not".  So your expression is matching anything not a number ([Carets in Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944357/carets-in-regular-expressions)).

The correct expression would be '/^[0-9]*$/' as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function num_only($num){
 // will return only numbers in a string
  return preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $num);
}
```

> 

```
function numeric($num){
    // will check if is numeric
    $int = $num;
    if(empty($int) or strcmp(preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $int), $num) != 0 )
    {
        return false;   

    }
    else return true;
}
```

> // will check if string is numeric

```
is_numeric($number);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this instead:
`'/^[0-9]*$/'`

Answer (score -1):

**Try this :**

```
/[0-9]+/
```

It matches any digits.

Comment: This works, but why not use the shorthand `\d+` instead? Or even more explicitly - `[:digit:]`.

Comment: @AmalMurali `\d` matches `[0-9]` **and** other digits like `Eastern Arabic numerals`. Since the question is about *only* digits from 0 to 9, it is more appropriate here to have `[0-9]`

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon you should use `^ $` delimiter. Otherwise, your pattern could also match **abc012345xyz** and this is not what OP wants