# How is it possible for replace function to work differently?

Tags: javascript, replace

```
string = string.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '');

string = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
```

This is the code that I found online. I am little confused about it. How come first line of code "excludes" special characters whereas 2nd line only include those characters that are only in []. Both functions are "replace" then how come they are doing totally opposite work.

Comment: It is a regular expression https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: https://regexper.com/#%2F%5B%5Ea-zA-Z0-9%5D%2Fg and https://regexper.com/#%2F%5B%26%5C%2F%5C%5C%23%2C%2B()%24~%25.'%22%3A*%3F%3C%3E%7B%7D%5D%2Fg

Comment: Different arguments are passed to `.replace`. Is it so surprising that the return value of a function is different for different input? If you don't know about regular expression, have a look at http://regular-expressions.info/ to get started.

Answer (score 2):

the first regular expression says: if you find any of these characters, replace them with nothing.

the second regular expression says: if you find any characters THAT AREN'T listed here, replace them with nothing.

`[^xyz]` matches anything but x, y or z.  The key difference is the '^' which, when it is the first character in a `[]` means don't match!

Here's a good link that explains [character classes and negated character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the caret (`^`) has special meaning when it comes directly after an opening bracket. It means "not the following", so when it is used in a replace, it will replace everything except what is in those brackets.

For a far more eloquent explanation, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16944517/3415209)

The first example does not have a caret after the opening bracket, so it will exclude anything inside those brackets.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I actually searched this but was not satisfied. Thanx for clearing it up.