# Why am I storing null values in an array using regex in java?

Tags: java, regex

My code

```
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = reader.nextLine();

    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^(<[a-z][0-9]>)|(<[\\/][a-z][0-9]>)");
    Matcher m = regex.matcher(input);

    while (m.find()) {
        listOfTags[i] = m.group();
        i++;
    }
    checkOpeningTag = listOfTags[0];
    checkClosingTag = listOfTags[1];
    for(int k = 0;k<listOfTags.length;k++){
        System.out.println("["+k+"] = "+listOfTags[k]);
    }
```

When I try to input `<h1></h1>` the output is

```
[0] = <h1>
[1] = </h1>
```

But when I input `<h1><h1>` the output is

```
[0] = <h1>
[1] = null
```

Why is it storing null value?

Comment: shouldn't this `k<listOfTags.length;` be `listOftags.length;` ?

Comment: Theres only 1 match, your array is of size 2

Comment: @rollback but how is it only one match? You mean if I have 10 h1 tags, it will only count as one? How can I count the  rest of the same match? Is it a thing?

Comment: I suspect you want to match opening/closing tag anywhere in the string. Remove `^`. Just use `"</?[a-z][0-9]>"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OMG Thanks! That sneaky caret. It worked!

Comment: @Yupyep also look at my answer, its bad practice to not check for nulls and length

Comment: A possible duplicate of [Carets in Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944357/carets-in-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `^` caret symbol in the current regex matches the start of string. So, the only opening tag that will get matched will be at the beginning of the string.

Remove the caret:

```
(<[a-z][0-9]>)|(</[a-z][0-9]>)
```

Or even merge the alternatives into if you do not need to differentiate between opening and closing tags:

```
</?[a-z][0-9]>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer, Im new to using regex

Answer (score 0):

to make sure you aren't exceeding the length of your `listOfTags` you might want to do this:

```
if(listOfTags.length >= 2){
    checkOpeningTag = listOfTags[0];
    checkClosingTag = listOfTags[1];
}
```

to prevent storing nulls in your list:

```
int i = 0;
while(m.find()){
    if(m.group() != null){
        listOfTags[i] = m.group();
        i++;
    }
}
```