# Regular expression to detect doubled vowels in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Can anyone explain this regular expression? This query is used in Oracle to returns the last name for those employees with a double vowel (where last_name contains two adjacent occurrences of either a, e, i, o, or u, regardless of case):

```
SELECT last_name
FROM employees
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (last_name, '([aeiou])\1', 'i');
```

The output is :

```
LAST_NAME
---------------
De Haan
Greenberg
Khoo
Gee
Greene
Lee
Bloom
Feeney
```

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/EuTfil/1, explanation is on the right.

Comment: Ok, see 1) [Carets in Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944357/carets-in-regular-expressions), 2) [Have trouble understanding capturing groups and back references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880127/have-trouble-understanding-capturing-groups-and-back-references)

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern `([aeiou])\1` simply matches two vowels in succession:

```
([aeiou])   match and capture a single vowel
\1          then match the same vowel we just captured
```

If you examine the matching last names, you will see that they all have repeating vowels in some position.  By the way, the term `\1` is known as a backreference, which refers to a captured quantity earlier in the pattern.

Explore the helpful demo below to better understand how the pattern works.

### Demo

Comment: can you explain this expression in more detail  ([aeiou])\1

Comment: @AnkitJuneja Have a look at the demo.  I cannot explain it any better.