# Get city name either do not start with vowels or do not end with vowels

Tags: sql

Query the list of CITY names from STATION that either do not start with vowels or do not end with vowels. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

Input Format

The STATION table is described as follows:

[image]

I write the below query, but it's not working for me. Any suggestion?

```
select distinct city
from station
where city regexp '^[^aeiou].*[^aeiou]$';
```

Comment: Which DB is this ? Most DB do not support regex. Use functions that your DB supports.

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: @AriSingh: actually most DBMS **do** support regular expressions. But as there is no real SQL standard (at least for real POSIX regex) the syntax is very different for each DBMS product

Comment: "either/or" sounds like it is allowed to *both* start and end on a vowel?

Comment: Based on use of `VARCHAR2` data type database is Oracle.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you are using MySQL, Here is what you are looking for

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station WHERE city RLIKE '^[^aeiouAEIOU].*|.*[^AEIOUaeiou]$';
```

Footnote : [RLIKE](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/regexp_rlike) and [DISTINCT](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/select-distinct)

What worked for me for MySQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station
WHERE LOWER(city) NOT REGEXP '^[aeiou]'
AND LOWER(city) NOT REGEXP '[aeiou]$';
```

Note: I'm quite unsure why, but RLIKE worked for the 2 challenges prior to this (start only, end only). Now, REGEXP is the only one working. Can someone explain to me why it is so?

Comment: You are assuming that the OP is using `MySQL`. Answering when the question is halfheartedly tagged, only serves to confuse anyone else who comes along with a similar question.

Comment: Agree! Edited my answer, though I just modified the query in OPs answer. Though RLIKE is different for diff databases

Comment: In MySQL, `RLIKE` and `REGEXP` are equivalent.

Comment: @AnandG What will be in the MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 12):

This SQL Query will helpful for you. 
If you are using MS SQL then follow this line of code given below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION  
WHERE CITY NOT LIKE '[AEIOU]%' OR CITY NOT LIKE '%[aeiou]';
```

If you are using MySQL then follow this line of code given below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE (CITY NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY LIKE '%a' OR CITY LIKE '%e' OR CITY LIKE '%i' OR CITY LIKE '%o' OR CITY LIKE '%u'))
OR 
(CITY NOT IN (SELECT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY LIKE 'A%' OR CITY LIKE 'E%' OR CITY LIKE 'I%' OR CITY LIKE 'O%' OR CITY LIKE 'U%'));
```

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM   station
WHERE  city REGEXP '^[^aeiouAEIOU]|[^aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station WHERE city RLIKE '^[^aeiouAEIOU].* 
 [^aeiouAEIOU]$';
```

You have to place caret character inside square brackets which means not any vowels. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16944517/4177764) is explanation

Comment: Works in MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
SELECT city 
FROM station 
WHERE left(city,1) not regexp 'a|e|i|o|u' or right(city,1) not regexp 'a|e|i|o|u' 
GROUP BY city
```

Answer (score 4):

This SQL Query will helpful for you if you are using `Oracle`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM station
WHERE regexp_like (city, '^[^aeiouAEIOU].*') 
OR regexp_like (city, '.*[^aeiouAEIOU]$');
```

Another answer if you are using Oracle:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CITY) 
FROM STATION 
WHERE NOT regexp_like(lower(CITY),'^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$');
```

Comment: Regarding '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$', how to understand the comma and star here? I saw this is a popular answer, but now sure how to understand the .*

Comment: 1. there is no comma, kindly check.
2. `.*` means string should start from either of (aeiou) and can have zero or more iteration of that letter.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select DISTINCT city from STATION 
where  (CITY NOT LIKE 'a%'
        AND CITY  NOT LIKE 'e%'
        AND CITY NOT LIKE 'i%' 
        AND CITY NOT LIKE 'o%'
        AND CITY NOT LIKE 'u%')
OR (CITY NOT LIKE '%a' AND
    CITY  NOT LIKE '%e' AND
    CITY NOT LIKE '%i' AND 
    CITY NOT LIKE '%o' AND 
    CITY NOT LIKE '%u')
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try this for MySQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CITY) 
FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY NOT REGEXP '^[aeiou]' 
    AND CITY NOT REGEXP '[aeiou]$';
```

This query will bring you the desired output for the asked question.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Simply skip those extra parentheses and write `SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM...`, to make code clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle solution:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE 
NOT REGEXP_LIKE(UPPER(CITY), '^[AEIOU]') OR 
NOT REGEXP_LIKE(UPPER(CITY), '[AEIOU]$');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[^aeiou]|[^aeiou]$';
```

this is what you are looking for bro.

Answer (score 3):

This is a required solution for MS SQL SERVER,

```sql
select distinct city from station where city not like '[aeiouAEIOU]%' and city not like '%[aeiouAEIOU]'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY NOT RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU]' 
AND
CITY NOT RLIKE '[aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution to your question should be the following query:

```
select DISTINCT CITY from STATION where CITY NOT LIKE '[a,e,i,o,u]%' OR
CITY NOT LIKE '%[a,e,i,o,u]'
```

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL
`Select DISTINCT CITY from STATION where CITY REGEXP '^[^aeiou]|[^aeiou]$';`

Answer (score 1):

I worked with this

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION
WHERE CITY NOT LIKE 'a%' 
AND CITY NOT LIKE 'e%'
AND CITY NOT LIKE 'i%'
AND CITY NOT LIKE 'o%'
AND CITY NOT LIKE 'u%'
AND CITY NOT LIKE '%a' 
AND CITY NOT LIKE '%e'
AND CITY NOT LIKE '%i'
AND CITY NOT LIKE '%o'
AND CITY NOT LIKE '%u'
```

Comment: In the question, It asks OR  not AND   ".. either do not start with vowels  OR  do not end with vowels."

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct CITY
from STATION
where SUBSTRING(CITY, Length(CITY), 1) NOT in ('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U') 
order by CITY
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Distinct
       City
From
       Station
Where
       Lower(Left(City,1)) not in ('a','e','i','o','u')
       or Lower(Right(City,1)) not in ('a','e','i','o','u')
```

Comment: Please explain why this is a valid answer and format the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE 
left(city,1) NOT IN ('a','e','i','o','u') OR RIGHT(city,1) 

NOT IN ('a','e','i','o','u')
```

Comment: please, the answer it would be more completed if you add some explanation text for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE NOT CITY RLIKE '^[AEIOUaeiou]' AND NOT CITY RLIKE '.*[AEIOUaeiou]$'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mySQL query:
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[^aeiou]' OR CITY REGEXP '[^aeiou]$'
```

Answer (score 1):

Right answer this  ,

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION
WHERE NOT CITY RLIKE '^[AEIOUaeiou]' AND NOT CITY RLIKE '.*[AEIOUaeiou]$';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct city 
from station
where city not RLIKE '^[aeiou]' and city not RLike '[aeiou]$'
```

Comment: Answers which contains only code are not considered as complete

Answer (score 1):

MYSQL:

```
Select distinct city from station where city not regexp '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$'
```

EXPLANATION :
    Using regular expression and NOT condition.
    So basically it is searches for the city which start with vowels '^[aeiou]' concatenated by 'n' values in between by '.' operator and second condition of ending with vowels '[aeiou]$'.
And at the end since NOT condition is applied ,so only the ones whic do not meet the criteria are filtered out and displayed.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE 
  SUBSTRING(CITY,1,1) NOT IN ('A','E','I','O','U') 
  OR 
  SUBSTRING(CITY,1,1) NOT IN ('a','e','i','o','u')
```

This code works for MS SQL SERVER.

Answer (score 1):

I use this and it works, its ORACLE SQL:

```
select distinct city from station where regexp_like(city, '^[^aeiou].*|.*[^aeiou]$', 'i');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Correction to the above statement using MS SQL SERVER is shown below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY NOT LIKE '[AEIOU]%' OR CITY NOT LIKE '[aeiou]**%**';
```

Comment: To filter out both the upper case beginning vowel and the lower case beginning vowel, shouldn't it be an `AND` instead of an `OR`?  Or better yet, just combine the cases, e.g. `WHERE CITY NOT LIKE '[AaEeIiOoUu]%' OR CITY NOT LIKE '%[AaEeIiOoUu]'`

Answer (score 0):

mysql query:
`SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station WHERE city NOT REGEXP '^[aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiouAEIOU]$';`

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct city
from station 
where not lower(substr(city,1,1)) in ('a','e','i','o','u')
      or not lower(substr(city,-1,1)) in ('a','e','i','o','u');
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do what you want. It worked for me successfully!

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY NOT RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU]' OR CITY NOT RLIKE '[aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

Comment: Avoid using all UPPERCASE for statements !

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using MYSQL. I also grouped the results by city, which is not needed...just prettier:

```
select distinct CITY
from STATION
where CITY NOT RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU]'
  OR CITY NOT RLIKE '[AEIOUaeiou]$'
GROUP BY CITY;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work the way you want:

```
SELECT city 
FROM station 
WHERE left(city,1) not regexp 'a|e|i|o|u' or right(city,1) not regexp 'a|e|i|o|u' 
GROUP BY city
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should add some explanation and also format your code (in this case with triple backticks and sql syntax hint).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct city FROM station 
WHERE City not LIKE '[aeiou]%' and CITY NOT LIKE '%[aeiou]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you saw this question on hacker rank and given your screenshot of the table STATION schema also tells the same thing. Here is my answer and it worked for me in MYSQL.

```
select DISTINCT(city) from STATION where CITY REGEXP '^[^aeiou]' or CITY REGEXP '.*[^aeiou]$';
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
SELECT CITY from STATION WHERE LOWER(CITY) NOT REGEXP '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$' GROUP BY CITY
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! When providing answers, please add context explaining what is happening in your code. Answers that are only code are not considered complete.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL RLIKE operator performs a pattern match of a string expression against a pattern. The pattern is supplied as an argument.

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station 
WHERE city NOT RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiouAEIOU]$';
```

Ref:
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-rlike-function.php
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Answer (score 0):

As the requirement is mentioned that the start and end should not be Vowel, here we can use a Pattern using RLIKE:

select distinct city from station where (left(city,1) not in ('a','e','i','o','u') and  right(city,1) not in ('a','e','i','o','u'));

Answer (score 0):

mysql

Answer for "dont start with vowels either dont end with vowels" is
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION 
WHERE NOT CITY RLIKE '^[AEIOUaeiou]' or NOT CITY RLIKE '.*[AEIOUaeiou]$' ;

Answer for "dont start with vowels and dont end with vowels" is
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION 
WHERE NOT CITY RLIKE '^[AEIOUaeiou]' And NOT CITY RLIKE '.*[AEIOUaeiou]$' ;

Comment: Welcome to SO! The first answer is identical to the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49229048/revisions, and is enough to answer the question. The second answer doesn't answer the question of either don't start with vowels or don't end with vowels.Your answer only either repeats a previous answer or doesn't add extra useful information.

Answer (score 0):

for oracle try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(CITY,'^.*[^aeiouAEIOU]$') 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(CITY,'^[^aeiouAEIOU].*$');
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY NOT like '%a' and CITY NOT like '%i'
and CITY NOT like '%e' and CITY NOT like '%o' and CITY NOT like '%u';

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle : `select DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(CITY,'^[^aeiou]|[^aeiou]$','i');`

Answer (score 0):

Simple MySql query can be like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY NOT REGEXP '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$';
```

Answer (score 0):

**My SQL Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION 
WHERE(CITY NOT LIKE 'u%' AND 
CITY NOT LIKE 'a%' AND 
CITY NOT LIKE 'e%' AND 
CITY NOT LIKE 'i%' AND 
CITY NOT LIKE 'o%') OR
( CITY NOT LIKE '%u' AND 
CITY NOT LIKE '%a' AND 
CITY NOT LIKE '%e' AND 
CITY NOT LIKE '%i' AND 
CITY NOT LIKE '%o');
```

Answer (score 0):

for MySQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY REGEXP "^[^aeiouAEIOU].*[^aeiouAEIOU]$"
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is for MySQL, just tried now, and its works.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY NOT RLIKE '^[aeiou]'
OR CITY NOT REGEXP '[aeiou]$'
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE lower(right(CITY,1)) not in('a','e','i','o','u');`

***For City not ending with vowel***

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION 
WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[^aeiou]' /*Checks City does not start with vowel*/
AND  CITY REGEXP '[^aeiou]$'; /*Checks City does not end with vowel*/
```

Comment: The question asks for records "that __either__ do not start with vowels __or__ do not end with vowels."

Answer (score 0):

Simple and clean answer:

```
select distinct  city 
from station 
where city regexp '^[^aeiou].*[^aeiou]$'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **MS SQL**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY NOT LIKE '[AEIOU]%' OR CITY NOT LIKE '%[aeiou]';
```

I noticed that most answers here uses "AND", but the question is to select cities that **either** starts with a vowel or ends with a vowel. So you should be using **OR**.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct city from station where city like '[AEIOU]%';
```

used **MS SQL**: only queries the cities starting with vowels with uppercase also results display in alphabetical order.

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL regular expressions are the same as in Python.

You can use regular expressions in this case as well.

1. Select the cities which start and end with vowels.
2. Next, put **not** in front, which will eliminate those cities.

The query will be:

```
select distinct(city) from station where not (city rlike '^[aeiouAEIOU]' and city rlike '[aeiouAEIOU]$');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE SUBSTR(CITY,1,1) NOT IN ('A','E','I','O','U') OR
      SUBSTR(CITY,-1,1) NOT IN ('a','e','i','o','u');
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58996949/edit) to include an explanation for your code. This question has more than *two dozen other answers*, many of which have good explanations. Without one on your answer, it's of comparatively low quality and will likely get downvoted or removed. Adding that explanation will help justify your answer's continued existence here.