# Regular Expression Doubts - somebody please explain this piece of code

Tags: python

Can anybody explain this piece of code

1. What does `^%s` mean? why is it used there?
2. the second `'%'` . what does it mean and why is it used there
3. what does `string.printable` mean?

   ```
   re.compile('[^%s]' % re.escape(string.printable))
   ```

Comment: Is this python?

Comment: yes it is python 2.6.

Comment: #3 = https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-printable/. #1 I think you are asking in context of a character class, is that correct? If so the `^` means `not` and the next is a list of characters for the regex to not match. Perhaps it is supposed to escape anything but `%s`, not clear to me. I think it would not escape any `%` or `s` found

Comment: ...Python _[2.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0361/#release-schedule)?!_ That's extremely ancient and should absolutely not be used for learning Python in 2021 under any circumstances. Find a tutorial from the last decade. Python 3.10 is the latest version.

Comment: Oh no my bad! i meant python 3.8 (i confused it with the tf version i was using)

Comment: @Chris - Perhaps a bit forceful, in principal?  "under any circumstances" - unless the user's system is restricted for an old(er) version for a reason beyond practical resolution.

Comment: @S3DEV, I maintain my position. If OP were actually using Python 2.6 to learn the language they'd be doing themselves a huge disservice. Tools like repl.it bring many languages right to your browser. The only valid reason I can think of to use Python 2.6 today is if you're working on a very legacy project, and in that situation I still think upgrading (at _least_ to 2.7) is worthwhile in virtually all cases. But under no circumstances should somebody learn Python using Python 2.6 today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Half of this question is a matter of regex syntax, and the other half is python's string format syntax.

1. In regular expressions, the `^` character **when inside of `[]` brackets** indicates negation. i.e. the opposite of what's matched in the brackets. [See a more complete answer on that expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944357/carets-in-regular-expressions)
2. Both of the % symbols relate to python format string syntax, which interpolates a value within the string you're `re.compile`ing. The `%s` indicates the `str()` representation of the "argument" to the format string, which is the term after the `%` character - i.e. `re.escape(string.printable)`
   [Read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples) for more examples of format specifiers
3. `string.printable` is a built-in method specifying "printable" ASCII characters - [see the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.printable)

In short, it looks like that line is compiling a regex pattern that matches anything **except** the printable ASCII characters in a string

Comment: Excellent answer.  Just to add, the `re.esacpe` function is used to add an [escape character](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) to those punctuation characters which require escaping, in order to be presented in the string accurately.

Comment: @BentHam  thankyou for your responses! Extremely clear and helpful !

Comment: @S3DEV this clarification helped! thankyou !!

Comment: @sudhanippani - My pleasure. For the benefit of BentHam's effort, please remember to help those who helped you, by **accepting the answer** (click the tick mark by the answer).

Comment: @S3DEV I just started using stack overflow for asking questions, so I genuinely missed it. Thankyou for letting me know!