# How to add conditional element to regex?

Tags: regex

Lets say I have this:

```
< hello!
```

So I just want to match `<`.

so I just do `<`

But what if it does this:

```
<< hello!
```

I don't want it to match `<`, because `<<` is a different regex expression I have (`<<`).

How do I make it only match `<` if it is it?

Comment: Check out the [`^`  assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16944517/5459839) in regex.

Comment: @trincot I don't see anything in the question about matching at the beginning of the line. Only if it's not part of `<<`.

Comment: use negative lookarounds so you only match `<` if there's no other `<` before or after it.

Comment: use quantifier for that position? `<{1}`

Comment: @JorgeCampos Did you try it? It will match each of the `<`.

Comment: Added dupe reference for excluding cases where the character to match is repeated.

Comment: @Barmar He didn't specify the structure of the sentence or the original regex, he just mentioned that he doesn't want it to match the double `<<` so my suggestion also works. I see your point though. And yes I did test it. https://regex101.com/r/zYrx3q/1

Comment: @JorgeCampos In your regex101, it matches the second `<` in `<< home`.

Comment: Note also that `{1}` is always redundant. Unless a pattern is quantified, it matches exactly one time.

Comment: @Barmar aah, I see what you mean. Thanks for the input!